# Swift Text View is not on the top of the text

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, textview

I have a problem with my TextView. When I open the controller with the TextView the text is not on the top, but in the end. How can I resolve this bug in Xcode 10?

I tried with this code

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToTop() {
        let desiredOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentInset.top)
        setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `scrollToTop`? If so, where?

Comment: I've put before the extension this "myScrollView.scrollToTop()"....you think I've call it good?

Comment: I thought you were using a `UITextView`? Is `myScrollView` your `UITextView`? Can you show some code?

Comment: Yes I'm using UITextView....in the code I have nothing, only some text for the UITexView and the extension.....I think the extension is wrong...do you have some idea of how I can resolve it?

Comment: The extension is correct. You need to call it, probably in `viewDidLoad`. You should do `myTextView.scrollToTop()` in `viewDidLoad`, where `myTextView` is the name of your text view.

Comment: I've tried but nothing...always the same

Answer (score 2):

I disable the scroll of the UITextView before the view is loaded and then i enable it again:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
```

Hope this works for you!